# ListFragmentのリストの内容を変更して再表示するには？

Tags: android, android-listfragment

`ListFragment`を使っているのですが､コードの途中でリストの内容を変えようと以下のように`Adapter`を初期化してセットしたのですが､リストが更新されずにそれ以前のリストのあとに追加される形になってしまいます｡

**コード:**

```
adapter = new RelatedVideosAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.video_info_for_smaho_item, relatedFormer); //relatedFormarには新しいデータのリストが入っています｡
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

どのようにすればリストを更新できるのでしょうか｡  教えて下さい｡  
よろしくお願いします｡

Comment: @tokoi様
編集ありがとう御座います｡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adapter.clear()`を使うことで更新できました｡

Answer (score 1):

実際に実行して試してはいませんが、
`RelatedVideosAdapter`が`BaseAdapter`を継承しているなら`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`で更新できるかと思います。

もしくは`getListView().invalidateViews();`でも更新されると思います。

Comment: すいません。記載にありませんでしたが、アダプタはArrayadapterを継承してます。

Comment: BaseAdapterに変更して`notifyDatasetChaned()`を呼び出したのですが更新されませんでした｡また､`invalidDateViews()`も試してみたのですがだめでした｡｡｡